# could not find driver (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = admin@example.com limit 1)

Tags: sql, laravel-5

the software is working perfect on XAMPP and WAMP from since i have uploaded to my Domain it gives me this error

https://snag.gy/qG5A9M.jpg

any help highly appriciated, i'm using godaddy vps server

Comment: check this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/could-not-find-driver-error-in-laravel-55

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer